# FMDB SQLite wrapper and user defined/custom functions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, wrapper, fmdb

I'm using FMDB for an iPhone app at the moment and I'm finding it... okay. It's a great little SQLite wrapper indeed.

FMDB GitHub:
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

The only problem is I'm needing to use a custom function. In SQLite I can easily do this by using the following syntax:

```
sqlite3_create_function(database, "custom", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &customFunc, NULL, NULL);
```

Except with FMDB I don't think there's a way to use a custom function?

Correct me if I'm wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FMDB seems a light weight jdbc like wrapper. it dont support too much customization. I like it for working basic sql query without going deep into the sqlite3 functions.

Comment: @karim Can you recommend any other SQLite wrappers for iPhone that will handle custom functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want FMDatabase's makeFunctionNamed:maximumArguments:withBlock: method:

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#making-custom-sqlite-functions-based-on-blocks
https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb.m#L1033

Answer (score 1):

FMDB is open source, you could add a wrapper method to wrap up creating a new SQLite function. Shouldn't be difficult. You can use the other wrapper methods as templates for how you should accomplish this.

Maybe you could contribute your additions back to the community?

Comment: That's an idea, I might actually have a crack at it.

Comment: or just create a Category for FMDB, as shown in https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/FMDatabaseAdditions.[hm]

Comment: @Fulvio - Cesar was using short hand. He's letting you know there are two URLs that are the same, except for their extension. The URLs work if you use `.h` or `.m` in place of .[hm]

Comment: Should really take a look at @ccgus's answer below - he wrote FMDB and knows what's up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the following should work:

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];

[database open];

sqlite3_create_function([database sqliteHandle], "distance", 4, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &distanceFunc, NULL, NULL);

FMResultSet *results = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * from stores WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, -37.77023, 148.089688) < 1"];
```

Obviously, you'd use `custom` and `customFunc` (or whatever) in place of `distance` and `distanceFunc` but you get the idea.